# "The global ID is not allowed" error. Calling in "{user-id}/feed" to post friend's wall.

Tags: facebook

I want to post to friend's wall.
To do it, I took process like below.

1) Get my friend lists(friend's uid list) with fql.

"SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"

2) with uid, I call facebook api like below.

uid: 02342424033

API: "/02342424033/feed"

3) And I got Error message like below.

"The global ID 02342424033 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead"

And now I'm confusing.
What Can I do??

What should I do to get "application specific ID" ???????

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to post to the wall of a friend. You can only post to the wall of the authorized user with `/me/feed` and by using the `publish_actions` permission.

Btw, FQL is deprecated and you get the friends much easier with `/me/friends`.

Comment: "/me/friends" seem so doesn't scrap all of friends.. Did I misunderstand?